# About a particular linear map between sequence spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $x \in \ell^1$ and $z \in \ell^2$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ and define a linear map $T_z: \ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^2$ as follows:

$y_1=0$ and $y_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}z_{n-k}x_k$ for $n\geq 2$. Then, let $(T_z(x))_n=y_n$ for all $n$. I want to show that $\Vert T_z(x) \Vert_2 \leq \Vert z \Vert_2 \cdot \Vert x \Vert_1$. My present work is as follows:

$\Vert T_z(x) \Vert_2 = \left( \sum_{n} \vert (T_z(x))_n \vert^{2}   \right)^{1/2} = \left( \sum_{n} \vert y_n \vert^{2}   \right)^{1/2} = \left( \sum_{n} \lvert \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}z_{n-k}x_k \rvert^{2}   \right)^{1/2} \leq \left( \sum_{n} ( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lvert z_{n-k}x_k \rvert)^{2}   \right)^{1/2}$.

But I can't seem to get further with this, since I want to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality here but it gets really messy quickly. Am I going in the right direction or have I made some flaw somewhere?

Comment: I am talking about sequences taking real values, sorry if that was not clear .

Answer (score 1):

Well, $T_zx$ is just the convolution of $x$ and $z$, so the inequality you want is just a special case of Young's inequality. In a discrete case like this Young's inequality should follow just from the triangle inequality in $\ell^2$ if you look at it right. Let's see: $$\begin{aligned}T_zx&=(0,x_1z_1,x_1z_2+x_2z_1,\dots)
\\&=x_1(0,z_1,z_2,\dots)
\\&+x_2(0,0,z_1,z_2,\dots)
\\&+x_3(0,0,0,z_1,z_2,\dots)
\\&+\dots
\end{aligned}$$

Sure enough; apply the triangle inequality in $\ell^2$ to that sum and you're done.

Comment: That looks really neat, but can you write the sums, you are taking a little more compact. I am not familiar with convolutions as such.

Comment: @Bartuc I'm not sure what "can you write the sums, you are taking a little more compact" means. If you're asking whether I could rewrite this in sigma notation instead of writing everything with those dots, yes I could. Not going to - I've given you the proof, rewriting in the notation you want is up to you.

Comment: I was given a hint that I had to use Cauchy-Schwartz but your proof does not use that, I guess that is why I am confused a bit. In the above answer of yours, should'nt the third '$=$'-sign be a plus?

Comment: I can't tell you what whoever suggested C-S had in mind. Yes, that was a typo, thanks.